# Change webappDir path and also WEB-INF path in a multimodule gradle build

Tags: java, build, gradle

I am migrating ant build of java web project to **gradle**. It is a **multiple module project**. There are 3 multiple modules and one root project.

```
RootProj -- module1
         -- module2/src/main/webapp/jspfiles + WEB-INF ---\
         -- module3/src/main/webapp/jspfiles + WEB-INF ---/
```

**Webapp files (jsp,js..etc) in module2 are same for module3. But WEB-INF is different.**
So, I would like to use webapp in module2 for module3 also.

How can I handle this ?

I dont want a copy of same files so that developers will not get confused by seeing copy of jsp/js.. files.